# Mutability of arrays in java

Tags: java, immutability, mutability

If a method returns an object from a particular array index, and then this object is modified, would this object only be modified locally or would the object in the array also be modified?

Is there a way to force each case?

Comment: Just try it by making a simple program.

Comment: 1) an object *is* itself, and; 2) an object is *not* cloned/duplicated during an assignment or when used as a method argument. (Those two pieces of information should be enough to answer the question even without digressing into reference values..)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object in the array would also be modified.  It works this way because, although Java is pass by value, it's passing the value of the object *reference*.  So in the end the array has a copy of the reference and whatever gets the result has a copy of the reference.  When you modify the object itself, you're modifying the thing that they both "point" to.  So both see the change.

The only way to make this not true is to make a copy of the element before you return it.

Alternatively, if you make your object immutable, you don't have to worry about these details because you *can't* change the object in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a [defensive copy](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=15) of the object if you want it to not be modified